# Tensorflow 1.1 MultiRNNCell Shape Errors (Init_State related)

Tags: python, tensorflow

***UPDATE***:  I believe strongly that the error is related to the init_state as created and fed into the tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(...) as an argument.  So the question becomes, what is the correct shape of, or way to construct, an initial state for a stacked RNN?

I am trying to get a MultiRNNCell definition to work in TensorFlow 1.1.

The graph definition, with helper function to define a GRU cell, is follows below.  The basic idea is to define a placeholder x as a lengthy string of samples of numeric data.  This data will be broken into equal length frames via shaping, and one frame will be presented at each timestep.  I would then like to process this via a stack of two (for now) cells of GRUs.

```
def gru_cell(state_size):
     cell = tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(state_size)
     return cell

graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():

     x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, num_samples], name="Input_Placeholder")
     y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, num_frames], name="Labels_Placeholder")

     init_state = tf.zeros([batch_size, state_size], name="Initial_State_Placeholder")

     rnn_inputs = tf.reshape(x, (batch_size, num_frames, frame_length))
     cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([gru_cell(state_size) for _ in range(2)], state_is_tuple=False)
     rnn_outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, rnn_inputs, initial_state=init_state)
```

The graph definition goes on from there with loss functions, optimizers, etc.  But that is the place where it breaks down with the following lengthy error.

It will become relevant at the very last part of the error that batch_size is 10, and frame_length and state_size are both 80.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-4c48b596e055> in <module>()
     14     print(rnn_inputs)
     15     cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([gru_cell(state_size) for _ in range(2)], state_is_tuple=False)
---> 16     rnn_outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, rnn_inputs, initial_state=init_state)
     17 
     18     with tf.variable_scope('softmax'):

/home/novak/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.pyc in dynamic_rnn(cell, inputs, sequence_length, initial_state, dtype, parallel_iterations, swap_memory, time_major, scope)
    551         swap_memory=swap_memory,
    552         sequence_length=sequence_length,
--> 553         dtype=dtype)
    554 
    555     # Outputs of _dynamic_rnn_loop are always shaped [time, batch, depth].

/home/novak/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.pyc in _dynamic_rnn_loop(cell, inputs, initial_state, parallel_iterations, swap_memory, sequence_length, dtype)
    718       loop_vars=(time, output_ta, state),
    719       parallel_iterations=parallel_iterations,
--> 720       swap_memory=swap_memory)
    721 
    722   # Unpack final output if not using output tuples.

/home/novak/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.pyc in while_loop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants, parallel_iterations, back_prop, swap_memory, name)
   2621     context = WhileContext(parallel_iterations, back_prop, swap_memory, name)
   2622     ops.add_to_collection(ops.GraphKeys.WHILE_CONTEXT, context)
-> 2623     result = context.BuildLoop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
   2624     return result
   2625 

/home/novak/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.pyc in BuildLoop(self, pred, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
   2454       self.Enter()
   2455       original_body_result, exit_vars = self._BuildLoop(
-> 2456           pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
   2457     finally:
   2458       self.Exit()

/home/novak/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.pyc in _BuildLoop(self, pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
   2435     for m_var, n_var in zip(merge_vars, next_vars):
   2436       if isinstance(m_var, ops.Tensor):
-> 2437         _EnforceShapeInvariant(m_var, n_var)
   2438 
   2439     # Exit the loop.

/home/novak/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.pyc in _EnforceShapeInvariant(merge_var, next_var)
    565           "Provide shape invariants using either the `shape_invariants` "
    566           "argument of tf.while_loop or set_shape() on the loop variables."
--> 567           % (merge_var.name, m_shape, n_shape))
    568   else:
    569     if not isinstance(var, (ops.IndexedSlices, sparse_tensor.SparseTensor)):

ValueError: The shape for rnn/while/Merge_2:0 is not an invariant for the loop. It enters the loop with shape (10, 80), but has shape (10, 160) after one iteration. Provide shape invariants using either the `shape_invariants` argument of tf.while_loop or set_shape() on the loop variables.
```

That almost looks like the network starts as a 2-stack of 80s and somehow gets converted a 1-stack of 160.  Any help on fixing this?  Am I misunderstanding the use of the MultiRNNCell?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `init_state = tf.zeros([batch_size, 2 * state_size]...`?

Answer (score 1):

Based on Allen Lavoie's comment above, the corrected code is:

```
def gru_cell(state_size):
     cell = tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(state_size)
     return cell

num_layers = 2  # <---------
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():

     x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, num_samples], name="Input_Placeholder")
     y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, num_frames], name="Labels_Placeholder")

     init_state = tf.zeros([batch_size, num_layer * state_size], name="Initial_State_Placeholder") # <---------

     rnn_inputs = tf.reshape(x, (batch_size, num_frames, frame_length))
     cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([gru_cell(state_size) for _ in range(num_layer)], state_is_tuple=False) # <---------
     rnn_outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, rnn_inputs, initial_state=init_state)
```

Note three changes above.
Note also that these changes must ripple everywhere that init_state flows, including especially if you are feeding them into a feed_dict.